# Run Winstone.jar without Jre

Tags: java, jar, winstone

Is it possible to run winstone servlet container in tiny core without jre? 
If it is not possible or any minimal jre setup available for this.

Answer (score 1):

General answer:

- You can't run JAR file without a JRE (or JDK ...).
- In theory you could use a 3rd-party tool to turn the the JAR file into an `exe`, but a better idea would be to install a JRE.  A >>full<< Java SE JRE.

Winstone specific answer.

- The documentation doesn't say so explicitly, but Winstone is clearly designed to run using Java SE.
- The original plan was for Winstone to buildable using GCJ which would allow you to compile it to native code.  However, the documentation states clearly that that goal has not been achieved.